# How to skip an update in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Hi I want to skip this update in Yosemite and cannot hide it by right click > hide update because the right click simply does not work.

Also tried in terminal:

`softwareupdate --ignore Pre-release`

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: If right-click on your mouse does not work, control-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll?locale=en) Apple page for screenshots.

1. Open the App Store Preference Pane: Go to the Apple Menu () and select System Preferences. Select the App Store icon from the list of Preferences icons.
2. Disable Pre-Release Updates: Click the "Change…" button next to "Your computer is set up to receive pre-release Software Update seeds."
3. Confirm Your Change. A dialog will appear to show or hide pre-release updates. Select "Do Not Show Pre-Release Updates," and your Mac will no longer receive pre-release updates.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/softwareupdate.8.html you will see that this can be fixed easily from terminal:

```
 softwareupdate --ignore RAWCameraUpdate6.05
```

I'm happy to FIX THIS FINALLY!

Comment: Before that, you presumably need to run `software update --list`.  “The identifier is the first part of the
                 item name (before the dash and version number) that is shown by --list.”

Answer (score 2):

Go to `System Preferences` > `App Store` > `Change...` (next to "Your computer is set to receive pre-release Software Update seeds") > `Do Not Show Pre-release Updates`